# java exchanging public keys through a trusted server

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I wanted to build a relay server to which can securely relay messages between 2 peers (for nat traversal purpose) for P2P communication. Particularly, I refered to the steps in the diagram in this [document](http://www.teamviewer.com/images/pdf/TeamViewer_SecurityStatement.pdf) for exchanging of secret keys.....

particularly, it says "public key of A encoded with public key of B" and vice versa. However, I stumbled upon a problem: When I use both keys to be 1024 bits, I actually got an `illegalblocksizeexception` when I'm trying to use the public key to encode the other.

Reading other questions, some answered that there is a limit to the size of the data that the public can encrypt using RSA. May I know is there some details that I may be missing out, that is omitted in the diagram, or am I doing the wrong thing, trying to exchange keys as such...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSA public keys cannot encrypt data that is longer than the bit-length of their modulus. Therefore, an 1024-bit RSA public key can only encrypt a maximum of 1024 bits of data. A 1024-bit public key file will be larger than 1024 bits, as the modulus is only *part* of the total data. Hence, a 1024-bit RSA public key cannot encrypt another 1024-bit RSA public key.

**More importantly**: you shouldn't be encrypting a public key with *anything*. Public keys are just that - public; there is no need for secrecy when it comes to their content. If you wish to "bless" a public key as being fit for a particular purpose, then sign it with a private key of some significance. Or better yet, issue a certificate for the public key from a certificate authority trusted by all participants of your protocol.